# Split but retain continuous strings based on multiple separators (python)

Tags: python, regex, string

In the dataset I’m working with, makeup phrases (i.e. foundation, lip/ lipstick, concealer, bronzer, etc) are bundled with previous phrases (see example below). How can I split up/partition the bundled phrases in the entire dataset yet retain them?

**sample phrases**

```
‘vamplipstick @’

‘208bronzer :’

‘jadefoundation :’

‘nc45blush @’

‘eyeseyeliner @’

‘kikomilanolips :’

‘235concealer @’
```

**ideal output**

```
‘vamp lipstick @’

‘208 bronzer:’

‘jade foundation:’

‘nc45 blush @’

‘eyes eyeliner @’

‘kikomilano lips:’

‘235 concealer @’
```

**code so far**

```
makeup = r"\w+\s+[@:]"
separators = ["foundation", "bronzer", "lips", "lipstick", "concealer", "blush", "eyeliner"]
[makeup.partition(<?list_multiple_separators?>) for makeup in df]
```

Comment: `str.partition` does not support regex

Comment: Use regex replace >> https://regex101.com/r/3jVlwT/2

Comment: hen, normally there are comments indicating the question is not clear before it is closed as being "unclear", giving the asker a chance to clarify the question by editing. I don't know why that courtesy was not extended here but if you edit to clarify now there is a chance it may be re-opened.

Comment: Thanks Cary! Not sure why this closed too. I tried re-editing the question but to no good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` to replace matches of the following regular expression with a space.

```
r'(?=(?:foundation|lips|lipstick|concealer|bronzer) )'
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g4h2uN/1/)<sub><sup><</sup>¯\_(ツ)_/¯<sup>></sup></sub>[Python demo](http://tpcg.io/qwBnYZUZ)

Python's regex engine matches one of the strings indicated, followed by a space, in a positive lookahead. The space is included to avoid matching, for example, `"lips"` or `"lipstick"` in `007lipsticked :"`. (A word boundary, `\b`, could also be used.)

Note the match is an empty string (i.e., a *zero-width* match). In `"jadefoundation :"`, the match can be thought of as the empty string between `"e"` and `"f"`.

The "desired output" shows the space before `":"` having been removed. As the space preceding `"@"` was not removed, I assumed the removal of the space before `"@"` was inadvertent, but please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

try using regex replacement

```
import re

data = """
‘vamplipstick @’

‘208bronzer :’

‘jadefoundation :’

‘nc45blush @’

‘eyeseyeliner @’

‘kikomilanolips :’

‘235concealer @’
"""
separators = [
    "foundation", "bronzer", "lips",
    "lipstick", "concealer", "blush", "eyeliner"
]
output = re.sub(r"({seps})".format(seps='|'.join(separators)), r' \1', data)
```

output:

```
‘vamp lipstick @’

‘208 bronzer :’

‘jade foundation :’

‘nc45 blush @’

‘eyes eyeliner @’

‘kikomilano lips :’

‘235 concealer @’
```

this will replace each term by itself, prepending a whitespace character...

Comment: Thanks! very helpful! How would you apply this code to a longer list of continuous strings (specifically multiple rows of dataframe)? The examples I shared were extracted from a full list of matches I found of continous strings.

Comment: @Chiheb Nexus was kind enough to improve the answer. it generates the regex now dynamically based on your list of separators. hope that answers your question?

Comment: yes, thank you so much! this works now and on the full dataset

Comment: You may wish to avoid matching `"shewaslipsticked :"` (by adding a word boundary, or example).

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

l = ["vamplipstick @", "208bronzer :", "jadefoundation :", "nc45blush @",
     "eyeseyeliner @", "kikomilanolips :", "235concealer @"]

[print(re.sub(
   r"^(\w+)\s*(foundation|bronzer|lipstick|lips|concealer|blush|eyeliner)\s*( @|:)$", 
   r"\1 \2\3", i)) for i in l]
```

> vamp lipstick @
>
> 208 bronzer:
>
> jade foundation:
>
> nc45 blush @
>
> eyes eyeliner @
>
> kikomilano lips:
>
> 235 concealer @

---

Test this code [here](https://www.ideone.com/teFyde).

Comment: Thanks! Definitely worked; how would I tweak this code to work on a list of re.findall matches?